# Add matrix name inside tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, tikz-matrix

I have this matrix and I would like to name it. I have to enter `H =` in the begining of the matrix but I cant. I tried with `\begin{bmatrix}` but I can't circle with Ti*k*Z.

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix  [{matrix of math nodes},left delimiter={[},right delimiter= {]}] (m)
{
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
};  
\draw[color=red] (m-2-1.north west) -- (m-2-3.north east) -- (m-3-3.south east) -- (m-3-1.south west) -- (m-2-1.north west);
\draw[color=blue] (m-2-6.north west) -- (m-2-7.north east) -- (m-3-7.south east) -- (m-4-8.north east) -- (m-4-9.north east) -- (m-5-9.south east) -- (m-5-6.south west) -- (m-2-6.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation*}
```

[image: matrix]

Comment: Try with `\node [left=5mm]at (m.west){$H=$};`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can modify the vertical position of the `tikzpicture` on the line with the `baseline` key, and simply write `H=` just before `\begin{tikzpicture}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
H=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(m-3-1.base)]
\matrix  [{matrix of math nodes},left delimiter={[},right delimiter= {]}] (m)
{
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
};  
\draw[color=red] (m-2-1.north west) -- (m-2-3.north east) -- (m-3-3.south east) -- (m-3-1.south west) -- (m-2-1.north west);
\draw[color=blue] (m-2-6.north west) -- (m-2-7.north east) -- (m-3-7.south east) -- (m-4-8.north east) -- (m-4-9.north east) -- (m-5-9.south east) -- (m-5-6.south west) -- (m-2-6.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I usually use `baseline=-0.3\baselineskip` in that case. Is there something that speaks against that?

Comment: @Benjamin Don't know. `baseline` alone seemed to place `H=` a bit high, and it seemed to make sense to have the baseline on the baseline of the middle row. That is of course not an option if you have an even number of rows.